# What package name does AdMob require for apps in the Amazon store?

Tags: android, admob, amazon-appstore

I recently tried to link my app which is on the amazon store to AdMob, I filled in the app name and package name as required `(package name: com.mycompany.appname)` and I received an error from google saying they can't find the app. Please does amazon store change my package name when i upload it or I should give AdMob the app id amazon gave to me(amazon app id:amzn1.devportal.mobileapp.1dd897e0f1ab48c181cdaxxxxxxxxx)
Thanks.

[admob issue photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLUSQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, Amazon Store doesn't change your app package name. Use the package name of your app to link it to admob. I got this after two trials. My app is now approved to show ads